# How to automatically have content size increase in UIScrollView on an action with autolayout?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout, uilabel

I've setup a test project ([project here](https://github.com/coolbnjmn/LabelScrollViewTest))  for this question to better illustrate my question, but here is the core issue I'm facing:

I have a `UILabel` nested within a content `UIView` which is itself nested inside a `UIScrollView`, and this is all laid out with AutoLayout. My initial layout works great, and the label is properly truncated to fit within it's content view as desired by the initial layout constraints. All is good so far.

Now the issue is when I want to add an "expand" action on the label. Let's say any tap on the content view should expand the label such that there is no longer truncation, and instead of truncating inside the `contentView`'s bounds I want the `scrollView`'s `contentSize` to increase such that the full label's text can now be scrolled. How should I accomplish this?

In the sample project, a tap on the content view will adjust the entire `scrollView`'s constraints just to illustrate that the label now has a different amount of space to work with. I'm stuck as to how to now have the `scrollView` recalculate it's `contentSize` such that the label no longer truncates.

I've tried playing with content compression priority, and changing that based on the action being done, like so:

```
theLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriorityRequired, forAxis: .Vertical)
```

But this doesn't seem to actually enforce that the label isn't going to truncate. I've also tried invalidating the intrinsic content size of the `scrollView` on the tap action, but to no avail. How do I toggle whether or not the label should truncate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you have a constraint which pins the height of the label or the view to your minimum height and when you want to expand you disable it (make it inactive) and layout the view. To compress re-enable the constraint and layout the view.

Comment: Not sure how this answers my question. If I were to have a minimum height constraint that would then be disabled on expand I still don't see how that would solve the issue that the scroll view content size isn't increasing to match the labels height should it be non truncated. I'm successfully expanding the labels size alongside its parent content view, but how do I enforce the label won't truncate? You're suggesting manually calculating the full height and setting a constraint for that?

Comment: No, the label has an intrinsic content size, the minimum height constraint would override that or allow it to take effect. If you have pinned the view to the edges and width of the scroll view then laying out the views after a constraint change updates the content size.

Comment: Still not sure how this is answering my question. My `UILabel` is properly getting sized initially in the collapsed state via a top/left/right/bottom set of constraints to it's content view. When I update the constraints of the content view's parent (the scrollview) to "expand", I am seeing my issue that the label is NOT updating the content size...I'm really struggling to see how this is an answer to this question

Comment: why are you updating the scroll view size? the size of the scroll view and the size of the label are effectively unrelated. you would usually pin the width to match and let the height be calculated. expansion should be on the label as it's the only view you have with an intrinsic content size.

Comment: I got this to work. Your answer was more like hints along the way, so I will expand on exactly what I was missing: in the sample project, I had center x/y constraints on my contentView to "make IB happy". I found that instead, I should remove these and pin my contentView's width to the scrollView parent's width, and similarly for the height. This height constraint is, as you suggested, the one I then activate/deactivate based on my needs. This achieves the exact behavior I was looking for. In this scenario, the label's constraints always stay the same -- pinned to the contentView. Thanks!